# QnA Maker Knowledge Base Not Found

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have an existing Knowledge Base in the QnA Maker that I am trying to update, however I am getting the following error: "You currently have no "knowledge bases", build one using the Create a knowledge base menu item. Learn more"

When I try to Create a Knowledge Base, my existing Azure subscription cannot be found.

Any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: can you see your cognitive services resources on Azure?Are you on the correct subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I recall there being an extra step of publishing the knowledge base after it is created in order to make it publicly accessible. As for the Azure subscription not being found, make sure you are using the correct login and that you are also in the correct directory. Associating resources in Azure can be a challenge.

Comment: My Knowledge Base has been published and is being used properly by my bot... I am unable to re-access the KB to make necessary updates. I am working from the correct directory too...not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @liverr1818 do you have more than one subscription? YOu may need to change the dropdowns at the top of the qnamake.ai portal to ensure you have the right subscription and cognitive resource selected. Sometimes mine defaults me to a resource with no KBs,,,